# Why are some npm packages listed in lock-file but not the package.json file?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-audit

I ran npm audit and it's warning me to update some of the packages. However the packages its warning me about, such as chokidar, is not listed in my package.json. So what does this mean? How do I perform an update if the package is not listed in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not listed in your `package.json` because it is a nested dependency.

You can update it either by trying `npm audit --fix` or you use the package [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions).

---

How to use `npm-force-resolutions`:

First add a field `resolutions` with the dependency version you want to fix to your `package.json`, for example:

```
"resolutions": {
  "hoek": "4.2.1"
}
```

Then add `npm-force-resolutions` to the `preinstall` script so that it patches the `package-lock` file before every `npm install` you run:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

Now just run `npm install` as you would normally do:

```
npm install
```

To confirm that the right version was installed, use:

```
npm ls hoek
```

If your `package-lock` changes, you may need to run the steps above again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which dependency is requiring the package that appears in the lock with `npm ls` command.
For instance for `sqlite3` you can run:

```
npm ls sqlite3 --json
```